# Select most recent record outer apply performance improvement

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: Client and Transaction (they can be seen as an example in this [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5792cdb62f37f2bcacf06f47d22c577e)). A Client may have thousands of transactions.
I'm creating a query to get a list of clients and their last transaction to know which ones are inactive (eg which have not made transactions in the last 30/90/180 days). And for that I'm using this query:

```sql
SELECT C.*, T.[CreationDate] AS LastTransactionDate FROM Client AS C
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 T.CreationDate
FROM T AS T
WHERE T.ClientId = C.ClientId
ORDER BY T.CreationDate DESC
) AS T;
```

And it works very well, but as the data grows so does the query delay. I've tested it on a table with approximately 50 million transactions and it took about 1 minute. What strategy can I adopt here to improve this performance?

Comment: *What strategy can I adopt here to improve this performance*. Indexes.

Comment: An index on table T `(ClientId, CreationDate)` should be beneficial.

Comment: [why not join  instead of outer apply in your query?](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=485c3f991024d0e96fc645360b5fea95)

Comment: @RF1991 you can answer that if you try both.

Comment: @RF1991 I would expect given the above index, that you would get a full scan and merge join if you join that way. Fiddle backs me up https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d264a546da4e1fb194b3577616c96200 Could be worth it if `T` rows read are a very large percentage, but if it's only a small percentage of total rows in `T` then `APPLY` is likely to be more efficient

Comment: @AaronBertrand I wasn't telling you off or telling you to correct, I wanted to know for myself. Thanks :-)